# Como ter mais de um valor referente a outra tabela?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Bom pessoal, venho com uma duvida que anda me perseguindo a muito tempo.

Vamos ao que tenho:

Tenho a **tabela X** porem valores da **tabela X** eu pego na **tabela Y**. Como armazenar mais de um valor na **tabela Y** referente a **tabela X** sendo que a **tabela Y** pode também referenciar com os mesmos valores para outras tabelas.

Com isso eu tenho um problema que preciso muito de ajuda.

O que penso?
Criar outra tabela para auxiliar estes valores por exemplo:

Tenho a **tabela X** e a **tabela Y**. Eu crio a **tabela Z** onde armazenará tudo o que **X** precisar na **tabela Y** assim caso eu tenha uma **tabela G** que necessite também de um item da **tabela Y**, armazenarei na **tabela Z** todos os item que **G** necessita.

Preciso saber se está correto este pensamento ou se tem outra maneira de realizar isso.

Pessoal, agradeço desde já. Obrigado por me ajudarem.

Comment: Pedro, me desculpe mas a sua pergunta está muito confusa. Muitas referências de X Y G Z. Não teria como postar as tabelas e alguns dados para simplificar a história? Assim que você simplicar eu retiro o meu voto negativo.

Comment: Relaxa, não ligo para seu voto negativo. Isso só desanima o interesse de quem procura ajuda, se vc solicitasse primeiro alteração na pergunta antes de negativa-la. mas tudo bem, já estou acostumado com a mentira mais antiga do país. De que o poder pode ser inocente

Comment: isso não tem nada haver com poder. Apenas queria te mostrar que a sua pergunta está complexa de ser entendida. Isso é uma comunidade, que ao meu ver tem o intuito de aprimorar o conhecimento de todos e nada haver com poder.

Comment: Minha pergunta foi respondida, talvez seu entendimento nao tenha sido suficiente e seu poder pode levar ela a negativa ou positiva. Nem sempre seu ver é o correto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo meu entendimento da sua pergunta, você quer puxar os dados de duas tabelas em uma só consulta, é isso? Se for, no blog do [Thiago Belem](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/relacionamento-de-tabelas-no-mysql) tem um artigo ótimo que foi onde eu aprendi, e [aqui](https://sqlfromhell.wordpress.com/2009/09/15/trabalhando-com-join/) tem um pouco mais sobre o assunto.

Exemplo: Você tem duas tabelas no banco de dados com alguns dados inseridos

```
CREATE TABLE `categorias` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
    `nome` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM;

INSERT INTO `categorias` VALUES
(1, 'Camisetas'),
(2, 'Canecas');

CREATE TABLE `produtos` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
    `categoria_id` INT NOT NULL ,
    `nome` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
    `preco` DECIMAL( 10,2 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM;

INSERT INTO `produtos` VALUES
(1, 1, 'Camiseta Social', 15.00),
(2, 1, 'Camiseta Regata', 11.99),
(3, 2, 'Caneca Grande', 12.00);
```

E quer um retorno mais ou menos assim:

```
| id | categoria_id | nome            | preco | categoria |
| 2  | 1            | Camiseta Regata | 11.99 | Camisetas |
| 1  | 1            | Camiseta Social | 15.00 | Camisetas |
| 3  | 2            | Caneca Grande   | 12.00 | Canecas   |
```

Deve montar uma QUERY assim:

```
SELECT p.*, c.`nome` AS categoria FROM `produtos` AS p
INNER JOIN `categorias` AS c ON p.`categoria_id` = c.`id`
ORDER BY p.`nome` ASC
```

Onde **INNER JOIN** irá fazer a junção da tabela *categorias* na pesquisa da tabela *produtos*. Que acredito eu, seja a sua dúvida.

(Fonte: Thiago Belem)

Comment: Recomenda-se respostas completas se links ou usá-los somente para complementar a pergunta.

Comment: Já resolvi meu problema. criei outra tabela para salvar a referencia onde o mesmo valor pode ser usado varias vezes. Uma tabela para auxiliar isso resolveu ! hehe .. mas muito obrigado só consegui com essa lógica que vc me passou. agradeço muito!